# Only write to log file if my log level is Info or higher

Tags: c#

I have logging module in my code and it is used frequently. First argument of each logging method is always the log level, while other arguments represent formatted string and its parameters. Parameters are very often calls to some other functions that calculates value of that parameter. E.g. when I want to print list, I use something like this:

```
Logger.Log(Info, "Printed list is: ", string.Join(", ", myList));
```

What is the problem with this? `string.Join(", ", myList)` will first be evaluated, then Log method will be invoked and inside here, based on current logging level, it will be decided if message will be logged into some file. If message won't be logged (current logging level is less than Info), `string.Join(", ", myList)` is evaluated for nothing.

Is there any way (without huge manual changes) to invoke log call and evaluation of parameters only if current logging level is at least the one specified in method call?

Comment: Yes, check your logging level before joining the string list together.

Comment: I made.... an _attempt_ ... at a better title. If the post now has a different meaning please fix it.

Comment: Hard to know what you've based this on exactly, but you can probably write an extension method for Logger.Log where you can compare the log level sent to a static/config setting held somewhere with a simple If statement.

Comment: .net core's `ILogger` system allows you to register a logger. During the registration you tell "what sort of messages are you allowed to process", of which you could say "only stuff that is Info or higher". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: The point of most logging libraries is to separate (a) the generation of the log messages and (b) the storage of the log messages (or choosing to ignore the messages entirely). Your proposed setup would undo that separation. While I can understand the need for performance gains, consider putting the log message generation in a separate task so it does not hinder the main thread. This way, you can retain the separation between generation and storage of messages, instead of delving into having to pre-check the log configuration.

Comment: First of all, thank you all for commenting.
@gunr2171 This kind of problem if of a more generic nature I think. It doesn't have to do anything with logging (see my reply at Hans's answer).

Comment: @Flater I'm not sure why do you think that this kind of code adding would undo that separation? Even if it would undo it, I don't see 'cons' of this approach (also check my reply to Hans's answer to see what i had in mind).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a method on your Logging class that takes a delegate as an argument and only call the delegate if you need to log the message. Something like this

```
 public static class Logger
 {
      public static void Log(LogLevel level, Func<string> delegateFunction) {
            if (level >= CurrentLogLevel)
            {
                 var stringToLog = delegateFunction();
                 Log(level, stringToLog); // Use normal Log functionality to log it
            }
      }
 }
```

Then you could call it like this

```
Logger.Log(Info, () => $"Printed list is: {string.Join(", ", myList)}");
```

Of course this requires that you have access to the Logger code. If you don't, you might be able to do it as an extension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This kind of logging would do the trick, but it would require adjusting of each existing method call. What i had in mind is that somehow tell compiler that each time my method is called to invoke specific check. E.g. to add some custom 'attribute' to my Log method definition and when compiler sees it, it would automatically insert code.

Comment: The hard thing about doing it without changing the calling code is that your message expression is evaluated before the call is made. So when you get into the Log method, it's too late. Maybe it's possible to hook into the code making the call, but that's above my skill level. It might also not be the most maintainable/obvious code to have in your project if other people need to work on it.